# Doing Landsat 7 pansharpening?

Tags: qgis, gdal, pansharpening

I downloaded a LST 7 scene from USGS, LE07_L1TP_193031_20181003_20181003_01_RT_B8 for those willing to try.

I created a band VRT, see below, which displays perfectly fine in QGIS and then a pansharpened version (see below again) which displays fine except that the colors are completely wrong, pulling towards the blue.

The instrument has some issues and I wonder if this could be the cause.

Does anybody know what could be wrong with my method?

That's my spectral.vrt

```
    <VRTDataset rasterXSize="8231" rasterYSize="7251">
  <SRS>PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32632"]]</SRS>
  <GeoTransform>  3.7468500000000000e+05,  3.0000000000000000e+01,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  4.7331150000000000e+06,  0.0000000000000000e+00, -3.0000000000000000e+01</GeoTransform>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">LE07_L1TP_193031_20181003_20181003_01_RT_B3.TIF</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="8231" RasterYSize="7251" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="8231" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="8231" ySize="7251" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="8231" ySize="7251" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="2">
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">LE07_L1TP_193031_20181003_20181003_01_RT_B2.TIF</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="8231" RasterYSize="7251" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="8231" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="8231" ySize="7251" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="8231" ySize="7251" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="3">
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">LE07_L1TP_193031_20181003_20181003_01_RT_B1.TIF</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="8231" RasterYSize="7251" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="8231" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="8231" ySize="7251" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="8231" ySize="7251" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

And my pansharpened.vrt

```
<VRTDataset subClass="VRTPansharpenedDataset">
  <PansharpeningOptions>
      <NoData>0</NoData>
    <PanchroBand>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">C:/Users/thomas/Downloads/Landsat7/LE07_L1TP_193031_20181003_20181003_01_RT_B8.TIF</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
    </PanchroBand>
    <SpectralBand dstBand="1">
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">C:/Users/thomas/Downloads/Landsat7/spectral.vrt</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
    </SpectralBand>
    <SpectralBand dstBand="2">
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">C:/Users/thomas/Downloads/Landsat7/spectral.vrt</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>2</SourceBand>
    </SpectralBand>
    <SpectralBand dstBand="3">
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">C:/Users/thomas/Downloads/Landsat7/spectral.vrt</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>3</SourceBand>
    </SpectralBand>
  </PansharpeningOptions>
</VRTDataset>
```